# Реализовать виртуальную машину наподобии CPython - C (СИ)

Tags: c, массивы, алгоритм

Хочу разобрать виртуальную машину примерно взятую с CPython.Немного
разбирал такую ВМ реализованную на Python.Сейчас хочу разобрать,сделанную на C.
Часть я здесь взял с файла ceval.c(CPython).Часть дописал сам-строку

```
unsigned char code[3]={ICONST,99,HALT}
```

Надо сделать так чтобы
прога выбирала опкоды c массива code и выбирала аргумент у ICONST.И выводила опкоды и
его аргументы на printf.Пока в коде запутано.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define ICONST 1
#define HALT   2
//массив кода
unsigned char code[3]={ICONST,99,HALT}
//текущий опкод
register unsigned char *next_instr;
//текущий аргумент опкода,если есть
register int oparg;


while(1){
opcode=*next_instr++;
//printf(<opcode>)
switch(opcode){
case ICONST:
(next_instr[-1]<<8)+next_instr[-2];
next_instr+=2;
//printf(<oparg>)
  //...
  continue;
case HALT:
  return;
}
}
```

Comment: Разпутываем вот `opcode=*next_instr++;` первый раз opcode = ICONST. При этом *next_instr у вас равно 99, потому что был ++. Проверяйте, делайте ещё раз `next_instr++` потом если надо printf и скорее всего `continue` я бы добавил. Всё.

Comment: Но данную задачу, лучше реализовывать массивом, где кажый елемент - длинна инструкции+тип аргумента.